# Обёртка над базой данных не "ложится" на схему MVC в Django

Tags: python, django

пишу мини проект на Django, который проделывает определенные манипуляции с БД. Возникла необходимость написать небольшую обёртку для кликхауса, к которой буду обращаться, и отдавать отчёт в json формате в гуй. Схема работы такая:
Ajax посылает запрос на определенный url, python вызывает эту обёртку и отдаёт результат в виде json-a, далее происходит некая магия.

Вопрос:
Чем в данном случае является обёртка? Она не ложится на схему model-view-controller. Как корректно добавить её в приложение Django? (возможно это отдельное приложение или какой то глобальный синглтон?)

Comment: Чем твоя обертка принципиально отличается от обычного view? который получает запрос и выдает пользователю данные в требуемом формате?

Comment: @AndreyMaslov У меня имеется класс обёртки, который умеет общаться с кликхаусом. Я хочу создать 1 экземпляр и держать подключение, чтобы из любой вьюхи мог в любой момент обратиться к этому экземпляру и выполнить запрос без дополнительных подключений. У меня возникла проблема с архитектурой. Я понимаю, что изпользовать глобальный экземпляр класса - очень плохое решение. Но не могу придумать других способов , чтобы не создавать дополнительные подключения каждый раз.